# I changed the duplex settings on my network card and lost vSphere connection, but through the KVM console I cannot find a way to switch it back

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

It lets me view the details for the network adapters, but I cannot find any way to turn it back to Auto Negotiate. I changed it to 1000 MB in an attempt to troubleshoot something, but as soon as I hit OK vSphere kicked me out and no longer works. This is all I can see with no way of editing:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get shell access like so: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1017910

Run "esxcfg-nics -a [nic]".

Answer (score 0):

This works on Esxi 6. On System Customization window, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Login using root username and pass then type this command:
`esxcfg-nics vmnic0 -a` or just type `esxcfg` to see a list of options.